# Cannot enter password in IE 10 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, passwords, internet-explorer-10

When trying to connect to any webpage, I can enter my user name, but nothing gets written when I try to enter my password. It works fine in Google Chrome, but not in IE 10. I tried erasing memory, cookies, etc. as suggested on other sites.

**Edit**: even bought a new keyboard in case that was the problem.

Comment: Did you tried to uninstall and then re-install the IE-10?

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue, seemed to be related to protected mode being checked in IE under tools>internet options>security un-check protected mode and restart IE. Started IE and I could enter passwords. Checked it again to test and I could no longer enter passwords. Hope this helps.